# Sperate Bootstrap css style for a single in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating a page in SharePoint 2010 and I want a separate style for this new page. I am using twitter Bootstrap. The problem I am facing is the default theme and all font sizes are changed because of Bootstrap styles.

Comment: You can override Bootstrap styles. But if you don't want the theme and fonts etc from it, what are you using Bootstrap for?

Comment: You could easily download a customized bootstrap version including only the desired features http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 0):

Create separate master page using Bootstrap styles and scripts. I would start with this and configure like you want: https://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/

Next create Application page which would use this customized master page. In application page's code behind use this to set to your new master page:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);
        this.MasterPageFile = "/_catalogs/masterpage/yourmasterpage.master";
    }
```